# EF7 Exclude Class/DbSet From Add Migration Operation

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-core

(Version 7.0.0-beta5)

Is there a way to exclude a class or `DbSet` from being included in the `migration add` command evaluation?

The database I'm building will include some tables that are replicated from another environment. They need to be included in the DbContext so they can be queried and joined, but should never have migrations generated for them.

What's the best practice in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of beta6, what works best for me is ensuring that the `DbContextModelSnapshot` includes mappings for the replicated entities.

Once the entities are mapped the migration scaffolding process compares the model snapshot to the entities to determine if there are changes. Since the entity classes match the model snapshot, no migrations are generated relating to those entities. When the `DbContextModelSnapshot` is regenerated and overwritten, it keeps the same mappings because there were no changes.

Also in the future there may be a feature to help out with this, as seen in this issue - no promises though, and not for the first release.
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2725

Answer (score 2):

You can manually remove the creations or alterations from the migration file.

Comment: Yes, think of the migration files as scaffolded--you own the output. The operations in them are just a "best guess" of what you're trying to create or change.

Comment: Yes, but I'm hoping to be able to avoid that. Over the course of development, there will be many migrations, and in a multi-developer environment, this becomes tedious and prone to error.

Comment: We do this all the time and it never created a problem